# how to get derivative aggregations on the simple count

Tags: elasticsearch

Using ES 2.3.3

I want to use a [Derivative Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-derivative-aggregation.html) but the metric that should be used to calculate it it's not something like `avg` or `sum`, it's just the raw `doc_count` of each bucket of the parent histogram (sales_per_month).

I got it to work like this, by using stats agg:

```
"aggs" : {
    "sales_per_month" : {
        "date_histogram" : {
            "field" : "date",
            "interval" : "month"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "sales": {
                "stats": {
                    "field": "price"
                }
            },
            "sales_deriv": {
                "derivative": {
                    "buckets_path": "sales.count" 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this really the way to do this or am I missing a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can get any simpler than that. It looks good, simple and elegant.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need do define a nested `stats` aggregation just for the purposes of referencing the `count`. There is an implicit `_count` property for each bucket which corresponds to `doc_count`, which you can use in `bucket_path`.

As in your example you're referencing a contextual parent aggregation you would simply only reference `_count` (i.e. you're already in context of `sales_per_month` aggregation).

In your specific case you would use it as:

```
"aggs": {
  "sales_per_month": {
    "date_histogram": {
      "field": "date",
      "interval": "month"
    },
    "aggs": {
      "sales_deriv": {
        "derivative": {
          "buckets_path": "_count"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```